# How to Add Expires headers for amazon s3 images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization, amazon-s3, paperclip

In my model, which is using paperclip. I have added [this](http://webonrails.com/2012/06/06/set-cache-control-expires-headers-to-the-content-served-by-s3-using-attachment_fu-or-paperclip/) line of code but still its not working

```
 has_attached_file :attachment, {
    :styles => {
      :medium => ["654x5000000>", :jpg],
      :small => ["260x50000000>", :jpg], 
      :thumb => ["75x75#", :jpg],
      :facebook_meta_tag =>["200x200#", :jpg] 
    },
    :convert_options => {
       :medium => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
       :small => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
       :thumb => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
       :facebook_meta_tag => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane" 
       },
       :s3_headers => { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000', 'Expires' => 10.years.from_now.httpdate } 
    }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

PS: I tested it on [GTmetrix.com](http://gtmetrix.com) and as per their stats, expiry headers are not there in amazon images.

Comment: Did you re-upload all previous attachments after making the change?

Comment: @James Do I need to? I was not aware of that. Please let me know if I have to reprocess all the images..

Comment: Any time you change your paperclip settings you need to reprocess all previous attachments if you want them to match your updated settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on James' answer for others unsure about how to reprocess your old attachments, there are two ways to do so:

1) Reprocess all attachments via rake (optionally per CLASS)

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User
```

2) Reprocess specific attachments (e.g. via migration)

```
User.where("attachment IS NOT NULL").find_each do |user|
  user.attachment.reprocess!
end
```

For more info, see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#generatingregenerating-your-thumbnails

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you didn't re-process/upload your old attachments and that's why their headers haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needed to get the URL of the attachment with a dynamic expiring header this worked for me: attachment.expiring_url(60 * 60) from paperclip documentation [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb#L183)